# we could pas REQUEST_EVABLE_BT so what is th need of intent for ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE

Tags: android

```
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) 
{
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
}
```

and what is the need of two parameters can't we enable bluetooth using single constant REQUEST_ENABLE_BT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line presents an "enable Bluetooth" action to the user. So here you're setting the action of your intent.

```
Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
```

This line is setting the result to come back to through the id `REQUEST_ENABLE_BT`, which is just an int that you define locally in your class. This can be anything. It doesn't have to be called `REQUEST_ENABLE_BT`...you can just pass in any int at all, then filter for it when you get your result.

```
startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
```

So in the Activity that's receiving the result, it would look something like:

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //int requestCode would equal REQUEST_ENABLE_BT in your case
    //so you would test to make sure this is the result you want by testing 
    //to see if requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT
}
```

Comment: how do i see the values of requestcode, resultcode and data (intent) if i want to see in android , how to print aur toast them.

Comment: You can just use `Log.d()` to print values to the console.

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept my answer if you feel it helped solve your issue. Thanks!